# Cassandra: updrage and search partition keys are different

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling

I have the need to **retrieve all requisitions with a certain status**.

I've considered creating a table with two columns:

```
Requisiton ID || Status
```

But there is a problem: when I want to update the status, I search for the **requisiton id** (thus this would be my partition key). But when I query, I search for the **status** (to obtain all requisitons with a certain status), therefore making this last one my partition key.

How to choose the partition key in this scenario? Making both **status** and **requisition ID** assume this role doesn't seem very efficient (since every record could potentially end up in a different node). Maybe a different database model is recommended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Partition Key` is used to identify which node data has to be written / on which node data exists.

`Clustering key` is used to order data inside a partition based on a column.

Assuming that the status column will not have high cardinality, it is better to use some other column for the partition key. For example, if you have a cluster of 10 nodes, make status as the partition key and status column can only have 2 possible values, then data will not be distributed across all nodes. One or 2 nodes will be overloaded and other nodes will have no data at all.

you can create your table like this, unless you have a better column for partition key :

```
CREATE TABLE requisition_status (id bigint, status text, PRIMARY KEY(id,status));
```

Defining your primary key this way will make your `id` as partition key and `status` as clustering key and you can use both of them in your query where clause.